# Axon multiple db configuration

Tags: spring-data-jpa, axon

Probably continuation of the topic: https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/provide-my-own-entitymanagerprovider/2149

I have got also multiple data sources and axon for dedicated one. I use Spring Boot 2.7.+ with axon framework 4.6.+.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61885471/9341865

someone mentioned that "If you want all Axon components to use a certain database, simply define an EntityManagerProvider bean that returns the EntityManager that connects to that database."

My question is how to properly connect bean of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with axon EntityManagerProvider - how to properly instantiate it?

I have sth like below but it doesn’t work (Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress) on access to event entry store.

```
import org.axonframework.common.transaction.TransactionManager;

@Bean(name = "axonTransactionManager")
public TransactionManager axonTransactionManager(@Qualifier("axonPlatformTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new SpringTransactionManager(transactionManager);
}   

@Bean(name = “axonEntityManagerProvider”)
public EntityManagerProvider axonEntityManagerProvider(@Qualifier(“axonEntityManagerFactory”) EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
   return () → entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@Bean(name = “axonEntityManagerFactory”)
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory( …
```

I tried also with:

```
  @Bean(name = "axonEntityManagerProvider")
   public EntityManagerProvider axonEntityManagerProvider(@Qualifier("axonEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new SimpleEntityManagerProvider(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
    }
```

and but ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider is for only one Persistent Unit (per doc)

```
   @Bean(name = "axonEntityManagerProvider")
    public EntityManagerProvider axonEntityManagerProvider(@Qualifier("axonEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider containerManagedEntityManagerProvider = new ContainerManagedEntityManagerProvider();
        containerManagedEntityManagerProvider.setEntityManager(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
        return containerManagedEntityManagerProvider;
}
```

but always No transaction in progress.
Could you please advice ?

Comment: That's odd and troublesome, @JJ36! I don't see anything that's amiss from your snippets, to be honest with you. If possible, I would like to retry your predicament on my machine. Could you for that end construct a minimal reproducible project and expose it on GitHub to share with others? From there on I am confident I/we can help you further.